# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined (WordPress)

Tags: javascript

I have a WordPress website, with a gallery. Everything was working till yesterday. I get an error when the user clicks on any picture to enlarge in the gallery.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at q (imagelightbox.min.js?ver=6.4:7)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (imagelightbox.min.js?ver=6.4:13)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at gg_throw_lb ((index):757)
```

I also see the following in my Chrome Inspect tool:
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2

Please help!!! Nothing has changed on the website or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we know enough about your setup to help troubleshoot this error but something was changed or added to cause this error.

My guess is that a value isn't being set so it is undefined and the library is trying to call variable.toLowerCase() on that variable. I'd look at what function you're using from imagelightbox.min.js and see what values it requires to be set. Track it back to where the data is coming from and see what value is missing. At the very minimum you can set a default value for that variable to empty string since toLowerCase is a string function.

If you want to add more information I'm sure we can help you out further.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue within a very old site.
Try updating the JS file for imagelightbox with the newest version(also an old update but newer that i believe yours is"

Here's a link: https://github.com/osvaldasvalutis/imagelightbox.js/blob/master/imagelightbox.min.js

-Assuming it's the same library.